# How to add \n in the beginning of number occurrence in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have an object that contains a huge text, like below example.

```
var obj ={ "text" : "1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex"
```

I need to add **`\n`** or **`<br>`** before the number occurrence.

I tried with `/([0-9])\w+/g` and join with `\n` as follows:

Please Run code snippet to see my result

```js
var obj ={ "text" : "1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex"}

if(obj.text) {
    let quote = obj.text;
    var regex = /([0-9])\w+/g;
    var result = quote.split(regex).join('\n');
    console.log('result', result);
}
```

My Expected output:

> 1This is the sample text.
>
> 2that I want to split.
>
> 3And add \n in the beginning of a number,
>
> 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string
>
> 4:1 for example i can have somewhere
>
> 5-6 also. How to achieve it
>
> 7Using javascript and
>
> 8regex

How can I achieve it using regex and javascript. Please help me out!

Thanks in advance. Best answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `var result = quote.replace(/(?!^)\s*(\d+(?:[-:]\d+)?)/g, '\n$1')`

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex:

```
/(\d(?:[-:]\d)?)/g
```

and replace it with

```
\n$1
```

Code:

```js
var regex = /(\d(?:[-:]\d)?)/g;
var str = '1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \\n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex';
var subst = '\n$1';

var result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('result: ', result);
```

The regex will match all the numbers and some non-numbers as well, because apparently you want to have a line break before `4:5` and `5-6` as well. The regex will match these and put what it matched into group 1. Then the matches will be replaced by a new line followed by whatever is in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
/\s([0-9])/g
```

To **[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** all the numbers which have space `\s` before it with a `\n$1`:

`$1` refers to the capturing group `([0-9])`

```js
var obj = {
  "text": "1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex"
}

if (obj.text) {
  let quote = obj.text;
  const result = quote.replace("\n", "\\n")
                      .replace(/\s([0-9])/g, '\n$1');
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Note sure. What browser are you using?

Comment: @adiga Don't think `(?<=\s)` is supported in most browsers, try `(?:)`

Comment: Firefox, last version

Comment: @nickzoum realized I can do this without a lookbehind. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a look ahead to insert a newline preceding a digit followed by either word characters or hyphen or colon using this regex,

```
quote.replace(/(?=\d+(?:[:-]|\w+))/g,'\n')
```

```js
var obj ={ "text" : "1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex"}

if(obj.text) {
    let quote = obj.text;
    var result = quote.replace(/(?=\d+(?:[:-]|\w+))/g,'\n');
    console.log('Result: ', result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` and replace any occurences where there is at least one digit `\d+` with `\n` + the number that was just replaced. If you only want to get numbers that are proceeded by words or empty spaces you could use the positive lookbehind `(?:^|\s|\w)`

```js
var text = "1This is the sample text. 2that I want to split. 3And add \\n in the beginning of a number, 4whenever there is a number occurrence; in this string 4:1 for example i can have somewhere 5-6 also. How to achieve it 7Using javascript and 8regex";

var result = text.replace(/(?:^|\w|\s)(\d+)/g, "\n$1");
console.log(`result: ${result}`);
```